# How to set page cache expires to 7 days?

Tags: magento2, nginx, varnish, caching

I am using varnish with default magento 2.3.3 VCL and the default nginx configuration that comes with magento install. At present I see the expires is set to -1. How can I set expires to one week?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> At present I see the expires is set to -1

The `Expires` header you see is *client-side*. Browsers should *not* cache things like product pages, etc. which is why the default Magento VCL [sets it to `-1` in `vcl_deliver` procedure](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.3/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish6.vcl#L208).

The `vcl_deliver` is what you use in Varnish for controlling the output to the clients (e.g. browsers).

How long *Varnish* will cache things from Magento depends on different things: the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` headers it sees from its backend (NGINX + PHP-FPM).

So while your client (`curl`) sees `-1`, Varnish uses/sees different `Expires`. You can confirm the same by issuing a `curl` request directly against NGINX backend port (e.g. 8080, if that's where it is listening) to literally see the same headers which Varnish will see.

```
curl -IL http://localhost:8080/foo.html -H "Host: www.example.com" -H "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
```

This would yield (for default Magento 2 setting with the expiration of 1 day):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 05 Jan 2020 19:36:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6ho2jvaeuiio58qb29cbnpmvaf; expires=Sun, 05-Jan-2020 20:36:08 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.example.com; secure; HttpOnly
Pragma: cache
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
Expires: Mon, 06 Jan 2020 19:36:08 GMT
X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cms_b_mpanel_default_sidebar_block,cat_c,store_group,cat_c_54,cat_c_p_54,cat_p_149,cat_p,cat_p_81,cat_p_42,cat_p_41,cat_p_118,cat_p_116,cat_p_105,cat_p_89,cms_b_header_1_social_block,cms_b_header_1_top_left_link,cms_b_header_1_top_middle_block
```

Take note of `Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400` indicating one day expiration. This is the TTL of a page defining for how long it will be cached in Varnish.

In this way everything works in harmony:

- Browsers do not cache website's HTML and thus never get stale content
- Varnish caches for as long as one day, and you can safely up this value to reasonably longer time, e.g. 1 week. Because Magento can "talk" to Varnish to clear cache as needed (when product price has changed, for example).

Now, of course you can adjust VCL to emit something other than `-1` for client. In this way browsers can cache things as well. But this is simply highly discouraged. Because there is no similiar mechanism (Magento->Varnish cache purging), which you can leverage in order to clear browser caches when you update a product's price. You simply can't get into those computers to clear the cache :)

> How can I set expires to one week?

This task is performed in Magento admin settings.

Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Full Page Cache -> TTL for public content.

For one week you would set this setting to value `604800`.

Answer (score 0):

@Danila I have some JS pages & for each page, I want to set a different cache. How can I achieve that? Is it feasible?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/195093)